# c++, creating vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, stl

Question is about what is the best way to create `vector` of `vector`s. I have several `vector<double> coordinates;` and I want pass them to function. How I should combine them, `vector<vector<double> >`? Is there more elegant way?

Comment: What's not "elegant" about that? Use a `typedef` if it gets too long to type.

Comment: Well, It is hard to read code. May be it is ok, because other approaches are even harder to read.

Comment: `typedef` makes it as easy to read as you feel like.

Comment: typedef is not a good idea, because it can introduce bugs hard to fix (see Scott Meyers, Effective C++, third edition, item 2)

Comment: @capoluca: Are you sure that's what he said?  (I only have the 2nd edition).  I find it hard to believe Scott Meyers suggested not to use typedefs...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth You should not believe him, you should just understand why he suggests his points. If it is make sence for you then you can use these rules. I understood his point about typedef. the fact is compiler will substitute them by code and during debugging you will not see names which defined by typedef. May be his point is more about using typedef for constant values. But, generally I understand that is better avoid typedef.

Comment: @capoluca: But I can't find where he said that!  Are you sure he wasn't talking about `#define`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It is in third edition. Item 2, first several paragraphs.

Comment: @capoluca: Not according to what I read in the preview on Amazon... he talks about `#define`, not `typedef`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like a reasonable approach.  If you're worried about readability, then use a `typedef`.

However, if all of your vectors are the same length (e.g. you're really trying to create a 2D array), then consider using a [`boost::multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just like you said looks fine:

```
void foo(vector<vector<double> > &);

int main()
{ 
    vector<double> coordinates1, coordinates2, coordinates3;
    //...

    vector<vector<double> > CoordinateVectors;
    CoordinateVectors.push_back(coordinates1);
    CoordinateVectors.push_back(coordinates2);
    CoordinateVectors.push_back(coordinates3);

    foo(CoordinateVectors);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that:

```
typedef vector<double> coords_vec_type;
typedef vector<coords_vec_type> coords_vec2_type;

void foo(coords_vec2_type& param) {
}
```

or with pointers to avoid copying if source vectors are at some place already:

```
typedef vector<coords_vec_type*> coords_vec2_ptr_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option woud be to put the vectors into an array and pass that to the function, eg:

```
void foo(std::vector<double> **vecs, int numVecs)
{
   ...
}

int main() 
{  
    std::vector<double> coordinates1, coordinates2, coordinates3; 
    //... 

    std::vector<double>* CoordinateVectors[3]; 
    CoordinateVectors[0] = &coordinates1; 
    CoordinateVectors[1] = &coordinates2; 
    CoordinateVectors[2] = &coordinates3; 

    foo(CoordinateVectors, 3); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Or:

```
void foo(std::vector<double> *vecs, int numVecs)
{
   ...
}

int main() 
{  
    std::vector<double> coordinates[3]; 
    //... 

    foo(coordinates, 3); 

    return 0; 
}
```