# C++ vector of vectors declaration

Tags: c++, vector, declaration

I am not really sure what this line of code does.

```
 vector<vector<A>> someth;
```

Does this mean that creates a vector with elements vectors with objects of class A? 
Can please someone explain this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660303/c-creating-vector-of-vectors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

Also note that your syntax is not supported before C++11:

```
vector<vector<A> > someth;
```

is the pre-C++11 syntax. Before that, `>>` was treated as the bit-shift operator, so you'd get a compiler error on some compilers.

This actually creates an empty `vector` that can contain objects of type `vector<A>`.

Comment: small detail, but I thought the syntax was acceptable in C++0x?

Comment: @helloworld922 c++0x is c++1.

Comment: @helloworld922 They expected to finish the standard sometime before 2010 so they called it (20)0x. They were wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this creates a vector whose elements are vectors whose elements are A objects.  It's worth noting that this declaration is only valid in C++11.  Before then, the `>>` was interpreted as the symbol `>>` (read from).  It needs to be declared `vector<vector<A> > someth;` (with a space).

Answer (score 3):

Correct. Basically

```
someth[i]
```

returns a vector. And

```
someth[i][j]
```

returns an A.

One thing needs to pay attention to is that there must be a space between two '>'s. Should be

```
vector<vector<A> > someth;
```

Comment: The space is only necessary for pre-c++11 compilers.

Answer (score 1):

yes, that's exactly what it means, it's a vector of vectors of A's.